# Cloud Functions Not Responding to onCreate in Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an index.js file that contains the following:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const trackVote = require('./trackVote')
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.trackVote = trackVote.handler;
```

I am then referencing the below function:

trackvote.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.handler = functions.firestore.document('/Polls/{pollId}/responses/{userId}').onCreate((data, context) => {
           const answerSelected = data.data().answer;

           const answerRef = admin.firestore().doc(`Polls/${context.params.pollId}/answers/${answerSelected}`);
           const voteCountRef = admin.firestore().doc(`Polls/${context.params.pollId}`);

            return admin.firestore().runTransaction(t => {
                        return t.get(answerRef)
                            .then(doc => {
                                if (doc.data()) {
                                    t.update(answerRef, { vote_count: doc.data().vote_count + 1 });
                                }
                            })
                    }).then(result => {
                        return admin.firestore().runTransaction(t => {
                                    return t.get(voteCountRef)
                                        .then(doc => {
                                            if (doc.data()) {
                                                t.update(voteCountRef, {vote_count:doc.data().vote_count+1});
                                            }
                                        });
                                 });
                    });
    });
```

Unfortunately, this method is not being invoked, however I do know that I am writing to the specific location in my Cloud Firestore. I also do not have any logs within my Firebase dashboard.

Below is the code writing to my Cloud Firestore:

```
    mPollQuestionRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
    RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        disableVoteButtons(group);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.string.vote_submitted_label, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        voteOnPoll((Integer) group.findViewById(checkedId).getTag());

        //TODO: add animation between between vote click and chart display
        mPollQuestionRadioGroup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mPollResults.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

});
```

Method:

```
 private void voteOnPoll(int checkedRadioButtonIndex) {
        int selectedAnswerIndex = checkedRadioButtonIndex + 1;
        HashMap<String, Object> firebaseAnswer = new HashMap<>();
        firebaseAnswer.put("answer", selectedAnswerIndex);
        mStoreBaseRef.collection("Polls").document(pollID).collection("responses").document(mUserID).set(firebaseAnswer);
    }
```

I can confirm that this location is being written to successfully as I check my Cloud Firestore within the dashboard.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the client code that adds a document that you expect to invoke this function.

Comment: Can you adda console log statement to your function? And maybe try creating the document manually, before trying with client code?

Comment: Did you save the file and deploy it to firebase?  Sounds simple, but I've missed it before myself.  Check to see if the function exists in the console?